# Vaadin Grid Lazy Loading Issue

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

**I should have noted that this is on Vaadin 21.0.7 ...**

I have an ArrayList of FinVizEquityInfoModel objects that is over 8000 in size. The objects have a lot of elements that are to be displayed in the user interface. So, this can cause quite a lag unless lazy loading is employed.

**The vertical layout and grid are configured:

```
        this.equityInfoGrid = new Grid<>();
        this.equityInfoGrid.setPageSize(50);
        this.equityInfoGrid.setSizeFull();
        this.setSizeFull();
        this.add(this.equityInfoGrid);
```

**ArrayList FinVizEquityINfoModel.FIN_VIZ_MODELS is used as the DataProvider.**

I have tried using DataView:

```
var dataView = this.equityInfoGrid.setItems(q ->
    {
        int offset = q.getOffset();
        int limit = q.getLimit();

        List<FinVizEquityInfoModel> subset = 
FinVizEquityInfoModel.getFIN_VIZ_MODELS()
            .subList(offset, offset + limit);

        return subset.stream();
    });
```

**The first time through, offset = 0 and limit = 50. This halts on the 'return subset.stream()' statement while behind the scenes, Vaadin repeatedly asks for 50 more at a time until it hits 300 or so, which takes over 2 minutes.

It then cycles through this code 5-6 times stepping up until offset = 300+; then continues normally. These cycles are very quick as though no real work is being done.**

I have also tried just doing a DataProvider:

```
DataProvider<FinVizEquityInfoModel, Void> lazyLoadingProvider
        = DataProvider.fromCallbacks(
            query ->
        {
            int offset = query.getOffset();
            int limit = query.getLimit();

            if (offset + limit >
```

FinVizEquityInfoModel.getFIN_VIZ_MODELS().size())
{
return
FinVizEquityInfoModel.getFIN_VIZ_MODELS().stream();
}

```
            List<FinVizEquityInfoModel> subset = 
FinVizEquityInfoModel.getFIN_VIZ_MODELS()
                .subList(offset, offset + limit);

            return subset.stream();
        },
            query -> 
FinVizEquityInfoModel.getFIN_VIZ_MODELS().size() // Max 
possible items to fetch
        );

    this.equityInfoGrid.setItems(lazyLoadingProvider);
```

The results are the same.

I cannot seem to find the special sauce to limit what the server wants to deliver (300+) v. what I need (25ish).

So, regardless of what I think I want, somewhere in Vaadin the grid is asking for much more than it needs, e.g., 25ish v 350 or more.

***What might I be missing*** in setting something in the grid (or elsewhere) that says, "only retrieve 25 records at a time"?

TIA!!

Comment: Appears this is a longstanding issue going back to 2018 ... Has anything changed?https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1576 @tatu-lund

Answer (score 0):

You can try different values of `Grid#setPageSize(int)`. Note forcing Grid to have too little page size can have counter effects too. By default the page size is 50. With this page size my experience is that Grid is fetching 50 - 100 items at the time in cases like yours (~25-30 visual rows).

Comment: Yes, that made sense to me. I have set the PAGE_SIZE = 50 confirmed that it is indeed 50. It appears that somewhere inside Vaadin the grid is set to something much larger, like 300. The code I show actually retrieves 50 at a time, it just keeps doing so until it hits 300. Then, things progress normally when scrolling. Driving me crazy. I will add more to the code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer here was lurking in all the other folks submissions: a layout issue.

Somehow, the minimum row height was set to something small, like the border height. This told Vaadin that you could fit some 200+ rows on the visible grid.

Fixed that to ensure the row height was reasonably calculated and things work as advertised.

As usual, PICNIC (problem in chair, not in computer).

Appreciate people taking a look ...